# Open any url in popup and redirect current page in ASP.net without any button click on page load

Tags: c#

When someone opens my webpage I would like a popup to open, and then I would like the main page (not the popup) to redirect to another website.

I have tried:

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(
    this.GetType(),
    "popup",
    "<script language=javascript>window.open('http://someURL.com','PrintMe','height=650px,width=1024px,scrollbars=1');</script>");
```

followed by

```
Response.Redirect("http://www.google.com");
```

While the redirection is working properly, the popup is not being displayed.

Comment: It might be possible your browser disabled the popup window

Comment: No i have enabled the pop up

Comment: ok then can you please refer my below solution

Comment: I think that's a breach of security. Be aware that modern browsers should block what you are trying to do by default, unless the user changes their security settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below code:

**Common function for open PopUp window:**

put this function at your common master page

```
function PopupCenter(url, title, w, h) {
     var child;
     var timer;
     var guid;

    var dualScreenLeft = window.screenLeft != undefined ? window.screenLeft : screen.left;
    var dualScreenTop = window.screenTop != undefined ? window.screenTop : screen.top;

    width = window.innerWidth ? window.innerWidth : document.documentElement.clientWidth ? document.documentElement.clientWidth : screen.width;
    height = window.innerHeight ? window.innerHeight : document.documentElement.clientHeight ? document.documentElement.clientHeight : screen.height;

    var left = ((width / 2) - (w / 2)) + dualScreenLeft;
    var top = ((height / 2) - (h / 2)) + dualScreenTop;

    child = window.open(url, title, 'scrollbars=yes, width=' + w + ', height=' + h + ', top=' + top + ', left=' + left);

    if (child.focus) {
        child.focus();
        parent.location.assign("http://blabla.com/");// Change parent Page location
    }
}
```

**and Call this function like below:**

```
PopupCenter('http://www.google.com', 'Widow Title', '1000', '1000');
```

in your case you have top apply like this:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(),"CallMyFunction","PopupCenter('http://www.google.com', 'Widow Title', '1000', '1000');",true);
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Thanks For solution its working fine popup is generated but after pop up i have to redirect  the current page to some other URL how to do this..??

Comment: do you mean you want to redirect parent page to other url ?

Comment: I have edit my answer. just added online line : `parent.location.assign("http://blabla.com/");`

Comment: Please mark my solution as solved if it helps you, thanks